# Debug react component rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, debugging

I'm trying to debug bug that is reproduced very rarely (once per several dozens of trys).

I'm inside of `render` call and want to find out as much information as possible from there:

- What caused rerender: `forceUpdate`, `setState` or `props` changed?
- If it was a `props` change, which component initiated chain of rerenders: I mean not the fact of parent render, but the top component from parents chain that has used `setState` or `forceUpdate` and so caused rerender of itself and the whole tree bellow (including the component I'm currently in).

It's guaranteed that all components are class components (not functional) and I'm using react 16.4.2 including deprecated lifecycle methods (if it is important). There are some usages of context too.

How can I make it? Note, I'm asking about debug techniques, not about fixing my concrete bug.

Comment: What bug appears? Would you like to show us how does it look or what does it throw into the console?

Comment: @kinduser, it's bug in my code. I'm accessing a business object in invalid state. In correct situation I should not access it in such moment of time. I'm using RxJS and think that there is some mistake in subscriptions, debounces or other async operations. If I could make an example of such situation, I would've fixed it already. But I can't, so here I'm asking only about debugging techniques, not about fixing of concrete bug.

Answer (score 1):

If your component is a pure component - `extends React.PureComponent { ... }`, you don't really have to care about the whole chain of re-renders, since it will re-render only if props have changed (from the chain or from the redux store).

It will not re-render if parent state changed or if parent basically has re-rendered.

**However**, it will still re-render - as I mentioned above - if props have changed **or** state **inside** that component was updated or `forceUpdate` function was called.

If you are not calling `forceUpdate` inside your component or you are not updating the state, the *issue* may be related with the props.

You could use e.g. `componentDidUpdate` and simply compare the `prevProps` with `this.props` and check which one of the props has changed.

Nonetheless, you can also check https://www.npmjs.com/package/@welldone-software/why-did-you-render package, it might be helpful for you.

Comment: I think, `componentDidUpdate` is not called if `render` throws. Anyway, it won't help me to find who does initiated a change until I'll update all components to have this trap. And If I'm going to update them, it's much more useful to set traps in initiators like `setState` and `forceUpdate`, isn't it? I actually hoped on react internal structures or callstack that would help to find the reason. And no, most of components are not `PureComponent`s. Anyway, upvoted.

Comment: @Qwertiy You mean "_`componentDidUpdate` is not called before `render` throws_"? Yes, it's not. If you prefer to see the previous props before render, you can use `componentWillReceiveProps`. Back to the topic - what I would do? I would change every component that is on the way into pure components, so I would be sure that they re-render only if props have changed. Then, I would add a simple `nextProps === this.props` condition in `componentWillReceiveProps` in every component on the way. The deepest (farthest from your component) one that throws `false` is the component you are looking for.

Comment: Also I've already found out that error occurs after new instance is created.

Comment: I think it's a bad sign - usually changing components into pure components shouldn't affect the application, besides improving it's performance. You have mentioned `forceUpdate` in your question - I guess you are using it commonly in your app? It's told to avoid using it since it violates the main flow of re-renders. Maybe that's the main problem?

Comment: Some observable initiates rendering of data. I want to find which one and on what level, as some data to render is not updated yet. There are some usages of `forceUpdate` or `setState` in subscriptions to observables. I'm definitely render invalid data and it's not the problem of react, it's problem of incorrect subscriptions. And my problem that I can't find which subscription and in which component is invalid.